# Ionic Framework : Android application runs web services well on connected device But in other device web service is not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Explain Difference between ionic run and ionic run -l

i followed these steps.

1. ionic platform add android
2. ionic build android
3. ionic run / ionic run android / ionic run -l

In 3 step , which option is better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ionic run**

> **Running on a device**
>
> What happens when you run `ionic run`?
>
> - Your files for the app are copied to the device (or simulator).
> - The app runs, thus firing a browser on the phone/simulator to run the  files that were copied over, something like: 
>     file://some/path/www/index.html.

**ionic run -l**

> **Running on a device with livereload**
>
> What happens when you run `ionic run -l`?
>
> - A local web server is started up.
> - The app runs, thus firing a browser    on the phone/simulator to run the files from the server    http://192.168.1.1:8100 (***or whatever
>     your local IP address is***).
>
> Your origin will be 192.168.1.1:8100.
>
> Any AJAX request sent out to a host other than 192.168.1.1:8100 will
>   require a CORS preflight request to see if it can access the resource.

**`ionic run -l`** is usually run on the simulator or device and any change made in the code refreshes the device or simulator instantly without having to install the APK continously - **thus making it simpler**. This command should prompt you with a list of addresses to select from i.e. Wifi or Ethernet. If this is not working then if might be that your ***CORS*** settings have not been enabled - To **[Enable](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)** - The Cordova [white plugin list](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) usually solves this issue

**Chrome://inspect**

Another way of debugging is to use **[`Chrome://inspect`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)** typed in the browsers address bar. This requires the Android device to have **USB debugging enabled** and pair with the development PC. This will be visible in ABD (`adb devices`) - non emulator - if successful. When the APK is installed on the mobile device and runs independently the chrome://inspect opens a Chrome Dev tools instance and shows all the debugging, console and error information.

I prefer chome://inspect to ionic run -l as it is a more *realtime* and true view on the functioning and health of the application. The browse will basically emulate whatever you action on the mobile device. This is particularly effect if you get the **white screen of death** - i.e. basically something in the initialization face broke and make it difficult to identify

Source: **[Ionic Blog](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/)**

Comment: Hey, one thing is that using ionic run commnad i can not access the web services. So , Give me solution as soon as possible. i have tried all those plugin like whitelist and all that.. but not work for me.

Comment: When using `ionic run` you need to ensure that your web service are published and accessible on the Wifi or Ethernet. Running localhost:8080 for example will not work when the APK is installed on the device. The web service must be hosted in IIS or Apache or even some cloud solution and exposed via the firewall to the open network be if wifi or cloud.

Comment: Thanks for reply.i had issue from back-end tomcat side. In the tomcat i have to disble/enable in web.xml file. tomcat server refuse to accept request of http://......

Comment: disable/ enable CORS filter on tomcat.